# Firestore query ends up creating multiple push notifications for the same information

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-notifications

In my Kotlin code I am querying Firestore for changes, and based on a condition, a notification is posted to the user. Is it normal for the code to be sending the same notification 4 times if 4 fields are changing in the database? i was expecting only one notification to be sent. my code is as follows:

```
docref.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("uid", userid!!)
        .addSnapshotListener { value, task ->

            if(task!=null){

                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            for (document in value!!) {

                val current_user_bid_lead_num = document.getLong("bid_lead")!!

                val new_user_bid_lead_num = current_user_bid_lead_num + 1



                docref.collection("winning_bid").whereEqualTo("previous_seller_id",userid!!).addSnapshotListener{value, task->

                    if(task!=null){

                        return@addSnapshotListener
                    }

                    for (document in value!!){

                        Log.d("userid",userid)

                        val losing_seller = document.getString("previous_seller_id")
                        val deal_num_lost = document.getLong("deal_num")!!
                        val winningbid_bid_lead_num = document.getLong("bid_lead")!!

                        if(usersid == losing_seller && current_user_bid_lead_num < winningbid_bid_lead_num) {

                            LosingBidNotificationChannel()

                            val CHANNEL_ID = "Losing Bid"

                            val intent = Intent(this, Mydeals_seller::class.java).apply {
                                flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                            }

                            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)

                            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.openbidicon)
                                .setContentTitle("OpenBid")
                                .setContentText("Your bid has lost the lead")
                                .setStyle(
                                    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                        .bigText("Your bid is no longer leading for Deal #${deal_num_lost}")
                                )
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .build()


                            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {

                                notify(id, builder)
                                id++
                            }
                        }

                        newdealnumref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")

                        newdealnumref.document(userid).update("bid_lead",winningbid_bid_lead_num).addOnSuccessListener {

                        }.addOnFailureListener{e->

                            Log.w("firestore_create_error","Error writing to document",e)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So I am getting the outcomes of the correct notification popping up but i am not expecting a notification because multiple fields have changed on the database.

As an example, `val losing seller` and `val winningbid_bid_lead_num` might change at the same time resulting in 2 notifications being sent. How can i limit this?

**Edit:** Having tested it a little further, i have noticed that the app seems to accumulating the notifications and even if i clear them and simulate the process, once the notification gets posted the total number of notification popping up will increase e.g. from 10 to 16. So is there a way to purge the memory of the previously cleared notifications.

**Update** - the issue seems to be related to the part:

```
with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {

                                notify(id, builder)
                                id++
                            }
                        }
```

But if i do not include the above i will not be able to show more than 1 new notification. Is the above the correct way of showing more than 1 new notification but not having android accumulate the counter and send the same notification multiple times based on the counter above? Example, is there a check i can run if that checks if the notification was cleared and if it was, then reset the counter to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Do Not use the method i used above utilizing snapshot listeners to check for changes.

look into utilizing cloud functions. as a newbie to app development it was intimidating to dive into them but once you have a base going cloud functions perfectly listens to changes to specific fields.